# Change store view programmatically using magento event observer

Tags: magento

I am catching the following event to do the further logic:

```
core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before
```

and in the Observer class I am doing this:

`Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeView);`

`Mage::run($storeCode, "store");`

but this throws an exception:

> Mage registry key "application_params" already exists

basically what I am trying to do is "changing the Language (store view) according to the current IP" and I am trying to achieve this through magento custom module.

I want to be able to change the default store view of magento, programmatically using magento event observer? and would it be possible to do so without redirecting to the selected store I mean by setting the values for store view before page load?

Comment: Did u get the solution for this? what are the steps u followed? I got struck at the same point from last 4 days. I too did created an event and called and the same switch case method and also the same error? please let me know.

Comment: unfortunately i had to redirect the page after setting the store, i left it there but kept in my revision list  but i wasn't able to get back to it. hopefully soon will get around it and have it fixed.

Comment: for the time being this code is working for me but i don't think its a good approach.`Mage::app()->getCookie()->set(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME, $storeCode, TRUE);
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeCode);
                    $_baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";`

Comment: Thank u for replying me back. I solved the issue and posted my solution below. Hope it may be useful for you also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. I have installed GeoIP extension. From this we are able to get the country code based on IP. I have added a function in the observer and this will be triggered only once on the page loads with the event `controller_action_predispatch` and in the observer, I use a switch case to switch between the stores. Here is my function & switch case.

```
public function getLocationInfoByIp($observer) {

        $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
        $cnCode =  $geoIP->getCountry(); 

        switch ($cnCode) {

            case "US": {
                  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                  break;
            }
            case "IN": {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('de');
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                break;
            }
       }
 }
```

Comment: this looks promising, i should check that and come back here for hopefully accepting the answer.

Comment: @MadMax Yes.. It works fine in both community and enterprise versions.. Take your own time to accept my answer.. ;)

Comment: Happy to hear that it works for you also... Cheers.. :)

Comment: Something may have changed. I'm in 1.14 EE and `controller_action_predispatch` isn't working. It's changing the CMS blocks/content, but not the layout or template driven stuff. I used `controller_front_init_before` instead and that's early enough in the process to work. The switch is the same.

Comment: I has to use ```cms_controller_router_match_before``` as well to ensure that 2 CMS pages with the same url key served the correct page in each store view. It looks like ```controller_action_predispatch``` doesn't quite fire early enough.

Answer (score 0):

U can redirect to the store view with the ip. No need to use Mage::run

```
  switch(trim($countryCode))  
                 {  
                       case 'CH':  
                                $url = $siteurl . '?___store=german';  
                                header( 'Location:' . $url);die;  
                       break;  
                       case 'DE':  
                                     $url = $siteurl . '?___store=german';  
                                     header( 'Location:' . $url);die;  
                       break;  
                       case 'IN':  
                                 $url = $siteurl . '?___store=english';  
                                 header( 'Location:' . $url);die;  
                       break;  
                       default:  
                       $url = $siteurl . '?___store=usa';  
                                 header( 'Location:' . $url);die;  
                       break;  
                 }
```

Comment: is this possible to do with out redirection?

Comment: Its possible but its a complex process

Default magento has its facility of Internationalization and handling of stores. So using it would be much easier

Comment: I got the same error as mentioned above. So I followed your solution. But now the redirection doesn't work and page loads too slow and the same event is triggered nearly 64 times in my application. So how can I solve this issue?