# Change store/website by location in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to change store according to location in Magento. For that I create a popup of location dropdown when user open website in the browser, he/she needs to select its the location and website would be redirected as per his/her input value.

```
public function getLocationInfoByIp($observer) {

        $location = $_POST['location'];
        switch ($location) {

            case "US": {
                  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                  break;
            }
            case "IN": {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('de');
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                break;
            }
       }
 }
```

When I submit popup after selecting location from dropdown, It change store. But after refresh it again change store to default.

So please suggest to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use any extension which provide geoip location

Comment: Possible duplicate of following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103103/change-store-view-programtically-using-magento-event-observer

Comment: @Muk I do not want to use geoip extention. Actually I want let the visitor there location and on the base of there location, I want to change store/website of magento

Comment: @Harit I have gone through this question. But here I did not get any help

Comment: You can get the ip address of the user and based on this you can change the store, but identifying the ip address for the particular  country will be difficult

Comment: @Muk I think you did not understand my question. My concern is not about to get user location. Location is provided by user him self. In other word, I am getting location. And on the base of location I have to change store.

Comment: Did you set a default store in your index.php file?

Comment: If you change page, you will not have $_POST variables anymore, you should also store this variable in SESSION or something similar in order to allow persistance of the location param.

But i don't understand where you are in the code... It's weird to do this kind of things in an observer method... Maybe yo can enlight us

Comment: @muhammedv no, I have not set default store in index.php

Answer (score 0):

This may occur when you set a default store in your **index.php** file, by editing these lines;

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : ''; //check this line

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

If you set a store code as a run code change it to default (blank) like these lines.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change condition

```
public function getLocationInfoByIp($observer) {
    $store = '';   
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    if($location=='US' && Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()!='en')
    {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');

    }else if($location=='IN' && Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()!='de')
    {
         Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('de');
    }else if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()!='en')
    {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
    }
}
```

Comment: this code looks same as I have used, In my code I have used switch case and you have used if else conditions